# Send Values via $POST from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, post

So, I have this site, and I created some buttons that makes cells in the table row editable:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWMiw.jpg

After the user edits whatever cells he wants, he should press "Save" button, as you see in the picture. Now I want to get whatever he wrote in those cells and send it to a PHP file, where every variable referring to a cell that the user edit will be validated. If they all are validated in the end, I update a SQL database with these new values.

Is there a way of doing this? Here is my script and some of the php:

```
<script>
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("clicker");

    var buttonclicked = function(e){
        if(e.target.textContent == "Edit")
        {           
            e.target.textContent = "Save";
            var id = e.target.id;

            var editable_elements = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable=false]");
            for(var i = (id*7); i < (id*7)+7; i++){
                editable_elements[i].setAttribute("contentEditable", true);}

        }
        else
        {
            e.target.textContent = "Edit";
            var id = e.target.id;
            var editable_elements = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable=true]");
            for(var i = (id*7); i < (id*7)+7; i++){
                editable_elements[i].setAttribute("contentEditable", false);}
        }
        };

    for(var j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++)
    {
        buttons[j].addEventListener('click', buttonclicked);
    }
</script>
```

PHP (to show why I need to pass this variables to it):

```
    else if($_POST["criteria"] == 3 && (!empty($_POST["g3"]) || !empty($_POST["g4"])))
    {
        apologize("This can not happen...");
    }

    if(empty($_POST["g1"]))
        $g1 = -1;
    else
        $g1 = $_POST["g1"];

    if(empty($_POST["g2"]))
        $g2 = -1;
    else
        $g2 = $_POST["g2"];

    if(empty($_POST["g3"]))
        $g3 = -1;
    else
        $g3 = $_POST["g3"];

    if(empty($_POST["g4"]))
        $g4 = -1;
    else
        $g4 = $_POST["g4"];

    $subject = strtoupper($_POST["subject"]);

    $normal = media($_POST["criteria"], $g1, $g2, $g3, $g4);  

    query("INSERT INTO portfolio (id, subject, G1, G2, G3, G4, criteria, creditos, normal) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE G1 = VALUES(G1), G2 = VALUES(G2), G3 = VALUES(G3), G4 = VALUES(G4), criteria = VALUES(criteria), creditos = VALUES(creditos), normal = VALUES(normal)", $_SESSION["id"], $subject, $g1, $g2, $g3, $g4, $_POST["criteria"], $_POST["creditos"], $normal);
```

PS: editable_elements go from 0 to 6, and include "g1,g2,g3,g4,criteria,credits" and another variable not important to this thread(but I want to send it to the php as well)

And the HTML part that can be modified is this: (remember that all the variables you see in this table were sent from another php file)

```
<?php $i = 0;?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
<tr class="d1">
    <td><?php echo $row["subject"] ?></td>
    <td contenteditable = "false" id = "<?php echo 'g1'.$i; ?>">
    <?php 
        if($row["G1"] != -1)
            echo $row["G1"];  
        else
            echo " ";     
    ?>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable = "false" id = "<?php echo 'g2'.$i; ?>">
    <?php 
        if($row["G2"] != -1)
            echo $row["G2"]; 
        else
            echo " ";      
    ?>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable = "false" id = "<?php echo 'g3'.$i; ?>">
    <?php 
        if($row["G3"] != -1)
            echo $row["G3"];
        else
            echo " ";      
    ?>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable = "false" id = "<?php echo 'g4'.$i; ?>">
    <?php 
        if($row["G4"] != -1)
            echo $row["G4"];
        else
            echo " ";      
    ?>
    </td>
    <td>
    <?php 
        $round = round($row["normal"],2);
        echo $round;
    ?>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable = "false" id = "<?php echo 'creditos'.$i; ?>"><?= $row["creditos"] ?></td>
    <td contenteditable = "false" id = "<?php echo 'criteria'.$i; ?>"><?php echo $row["criteria"];?></td>
    <td><button class = "clicker" id = "<?php echo $i; ?>">Edit</button></td>
</tr>
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: So make an XMLHttpRequest....

Comment: what is your html code?

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily by 2 methods

1. you can use ajax to send values to php file.
2. you can create dynamic form using script and post all values by submitting it.

Comment: I tried to do it with AJAX, but console is not logging the data, could you help me and try to explain me what is going wrong?: http://pastie.org/10574618  You can see the script down there

Comment: Are you printing any thing on edit.php. data variable will have all info you have echo / print on edit. php. As well as you can check various status of ajax. Please refer http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for more details